# Get image from Firebase Storage, from different Fragment from where It was uploaded

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I have uploaded images to Firebase Storage I a Fragment called, PostAJobFragment. In this fragment the user enters details, such as the job name, description and they must upload an image.

The data such as the name and description are saved in the Firebase Database and the Image is saved In the Firebase Storage area.

All of the Jobs that are uploaded the the Database Area are saved under a unique key. The same unique key is used to store the image relating to that Job in the storage area. 
So, lets say the Job in the database has a key "-L8rPGlikrxBnkP5PzLC", the same key is used in the storage are to store the Jobs Image.

Is their an efficent and easy way to get the image out of the Firebase Storage area to display to the user again on different Fragments?

So far I have saved the URL address for the image under the Job in the database and used Picasso to display the image. I feel their must be a better way than this?

**Example of Database Structure**

[image: Example of database Structure]

Comment: save image url inside job storage area !

Comment: That's what I have done, however, it seems really inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: i think there is no more efficient method than this !

Comment: What seems inefficient about it?

Comment: I felt it was as the images take a few seconds to load the first time that page is viewed which is slightly annoying. I was unsure if their was a better way